# What does this theorem mean, exactly?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> The polynomial $X^{p^n}-X$ is precisely the product of all the distinct irreducible polynomials in $F_p[X]$ of degree $d$ where $d$ runs through all the divisors of $n$.

I don't even get the statement. Does "distinct irreducible polynomials" mean distinct irreducible polynomials **modulo** units??

Moreover, I don't get the proof.

Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial in $F_p[X]$ of degree $d$ where $d$ divides $n$ and $\alpha$ be a root of $f$ in $F_{p^n}$

Since $X^{p^n}-X$ is separable, $F_{p^n}/F_p$ is a Galois extension and since it is cyclic, $F_p(\alpha)/F_p$ is a Galois extension.

Hence, $f$ splits over $F_p(\alpha)$.

The above argument means this:

Let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{p^n}$ be elements of $F_{p^n}$.

Then, $X^{p^n}-X=\prod_{i=1}^{p^n} (X-\alpha_i)$.

If $f_j$'s are distinct **monic** irreducible polynomial dividing $X^{p^n}-X$, then we can partition $F_{p^n}$ into the roots of $f_j$'s.

These are all I know. But why $X^{p^n}-X$ the prodct of irreducible polynomials of degree $d$ dividing $n$, instead of polynomials dividing $X^{p^n}-X$??

Comment: It is the product of MONIC irreducibles etcetera.

Comment: Ok then the theorem sounds ok. But what about my last sentence? Where am I missing??

Comment: Every polynomial is trivially the product of its factors, so if you say "$X^{p^n}-X$ is the product of (monic irreducible) polynomials dividing $X^{p^n}-X$", you are not saying anything interesting. What is interesting is instead the following. If $d | n$ then every irreducible of degree $d$ divides $X^{p^n}-X$.

Comment: @Crostul How do I prove that? Would you please write that as an answer?

Comment: Split the product $\prod_i (X-\alpha_i)$ into two parts $$\prod_i (X-\alpha_i) = \prod_{f(\alpha_i)=0} (X-\alpha_i) \cdot \prod_{f(\alpha_i) \neq 0} (X-\alpha_i)$$ and realize that $f= \prod_{f(\alpha_i)=0} (X-\alpha_i)$.